# Paperclip isn't storing file on my inherited model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, single-table-inheritance, sti

(I am new to paperclip)

I have this model hierarchy:

base model:

```
class QuestDescription < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

inherited model:

```
class ImageDescription < QuestDescription
  has_attached_file :img
end
```

and I'm using Single Table Inheritance from ActiveRecord

[part of] schema.rb:

```
create_table "quest_descriptions", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "type"
  t.datetime "img_updated_at"
  t.integer  "img_file_size"
  t.string   "img_file_name"
  t.string   "img_content_type"
  t.datetime "created_at",         :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",         :null => false
end
```

ImageDescription controller:

```
class ImageDescriptionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @imgD = ImageDescription.new
  end

  def create
    @imgD=ImageDescription.new(params[:imgD])
    if @imgD.save
      redirect_to :back, :flash => {:notice => "saved"} 
    else
      redirect_to :back, :flash => {:error => "error"} 
    end
  end

  def show
    @imgD=ImageDescription.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

new view (using formtastic):

```
<%= semantic_form_for @imgD do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :img%>
  <%= form.actions %>
<%end%>
```

show view:

```
<%= image_tag @imgD.img.url %>
```

when i use the new view (and select the file to upload), the POST is working, but no file is being saved/attached, the "img_file_size", "img_file_name", "img_content_type" are set to nil.

If I try to show it, the result is a "missing" field.

EDIT:

if i try to create a ImageDscription from the console, it works:

```
ImageDescription.create(:img => File.new(Rails.root + "public/images/grid.png"))
    (0.1ms) begin transaction
    SQL (31.9ms) INSERT INTO "quest_descriptions" ("created_at", "img_content_type", "img_file_name", "img_file_size", "img_updated_at", "type", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ["created_at", Wed, 15 Feb 2012 00:07:48 UTC +00:00], ["img_content_type", "image/png"], ["img_file_name", "grid.png"], ["img_file_size", 206], ["img_updated_at", Wed, 15 Feb 2012 00:07:48 UTC +00:00], ["type", "ImageDescription"], ["updated_at", Wed, 15 Feb 2012 00:07:48 UTC +00:00] commit transaction
    => #
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really stupid mistake:

```
@imgD=ImageDescription.new(params[:imgD])
```

means nothing... right line is

```
@imgD=ImageDescription.new(params[:image_description])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need define your post contain some file inside with multipart HTML tag

```
<%= semantic_form_for @imgD, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :img%>
  <%= form.actions %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but nothing changed: enctype="multipart/form-data" was already in the HTML of the form (i read somewhere that's automagical from rails 3.1)